# PHP blank space with 3DES Encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, des

I have a problem (server side) when i encrypt data from a client and i send to webserver with Post Method.

i Use this Method to Encrypt from a C# Client

```
public string Encrypt3DES(string strString)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        DES.Key = Encoding.GetBytes(this.Key);
        DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        DES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        ICryptoTransform DESEncrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();

        byte[] Buffer = encoding.GetBytes(strString);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length));
    }
```

When i send ecrypted String to PHP if there was a + in that string,  php read it with a blank space. If instead there'isnt any '+' i haven't any problem.

For Example this is a Encrypted String 4aY+na42iaPg+aep== in C# when i read in php it's 
4aY a42iaPg aep== so if i decrypt if dont match with the correct word.

i use this script to start read method post

```
   if (isset($_POST['doConvalid'])){    
if ($_POST['doConvalid']=='Convalid')
{
    foreach($_POST as $keys => $values) {
    $data[$keys] =($values); // post variables are filtered
}

$cheking=$data['check'];
echo("Show checking = $checking"); //Here i read string with blank space instead +
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes base64 decodes + to space use this:

```
echo str_replace(" ","+",$_POST['string']);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the '+' with a different character (something not used by base64) for sending. Then replace that character back to '+' for decoding.